# Create file PHP file on form submit and frwite to it

Tags: php, html, forms

Here's my code:

### **The PHP Code**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    $title ='myPost.php';
    echo $title;
    //the data

    $data = "Hey I am Aidan\n";

    //open the file and choose the mode

    $fh = fopen($title, "a");
    fwrite($fh, $data);

    //close the file

    fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

### **The HTML Form Code**

```
<form action="<?php echo $title; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When form is submitted I want to load that newly created file on the next page.

Comment: So what's the issue? Instead of action now use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] then use a header redirect to your new page

Comment: Another issue is that it won't create a new file either

Comment: Generating a php file on server from user submitted data seams like a bad idea.

Comment: @aidangig did you win?

Comment: @JayStar yes I got it resolved

Comment: Okay thats good. @aidangig mark it solved if help you got helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this is php to move to next page .   `header('Location: /somewhere');`
write this code in php tags of which you displayed in html and in place of somewhere you have to write the name of your file.php ... also write this code in first line of your php document inside php tags  ob_start();

Comment: Good suggestion, however the problem is that it is not creating a new file when the form is submitted. Therefore, it will not be able to open a new file from header code.

Comment: @aidangig your original post doesn't mention at all that the file fails to be created. This part "*When form is submitted I want to load that newly created file on the next page.*" suggests that the file is created successfully but you just want to know how to send the user there!

Comment: header('Location: /somewhere'); code in your php code where you write this condition . if(isset($_POST..... when you will click on button and condition will ture and it will direct you to your given page in header

Comment: <form action="<?php echo $title; ?>" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit">
</form>   here the meaning your code is that you are just print title in echo not directing to your page etc... just remove code in action . action is use for sending your html form into to some other page which you write or which you addressed in action

Comment: @Laiq Khan you are right in the manner that it just echos and does not redirect. I removed the form action="" to blank and it still is not redirecting me...

Comment: @Laiq Khan Can I put variables in header: header('Location: '/'.$dir_auth1.'/'.$title'); let me know please.

Comment: there is no need to put varible just write down the address of your php file . like yourdocument.php

Comment: if you are getting address from file then you just have to open file and get the content from file but it must be according to url rules . mean it must be point to write file location.

Answer (score 0):

After you close the file, redirect the user to it:

```
//close the file
fclose($fh);

// eg: /path/to/page.php. Also try $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
$currentPath = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

// replace the old filename with $title
$newPath = preg_replace('#(.*/)[^/]*#','$1' . $title, $currentPath);

// Redirect browser to new file and stop.
header("Location: $newPath");
exit;
```